# C# simple app create enormous number in page faults. Why?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-3.0

Have simple C# console app which imports text data into SQL.

It takes around 300K in memory and 80% in CPU. There are 2Gb RAM available at any time and yet the Page Fault shows 500K.

The app is 32 bit and OS is either W2000 or XP 32 bit and .NET 3.5

Anyone can explain what could be the problem and how can I investigate this further?

EDIT: I am now certain that the page faults are related to the disk I/O (read). I commented out SQL part and the pure disk read generates that high number alone.

EDIT2: There are 200 hard faults/sec and 4000 soft faults/sec on average.

I wonder if the same would appear on W2008

Comment: You should probably provide some code...

Comment: with the given information, the most accurate answer is that it's causing lots of page faults.

Comment: 500k page faults when? Immediately after the application starts, or after running for two weeks? How fast does it grow once the application has started?

Comment: MSSQL? Ado.net or some other driver? My guess would be a fault with a driver somewhere, or not releasing a non managed resource...

Comment: Most likely the page faults are related to the high disk I/O. See the edit in the question

Comment: @Bobb What makes you think you have a problem?

Comment: I never said I believe I have a problem. This question is part of another investigation where is no specific suspect but the high number of page faults... So I need to ensure there is no problem.

Comment: as per text above :) ->> EDIT2: There are 200 hard faults/sec and 4000 soft faults/sec on average.

Comment: @Bobb what is your expectation for these statistics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, how do you measure the memory the app is using? If you're looking at "working set" that's only the part that resides in physical memory. You should also take a look at the "VM Size" (or "Commit Size") where the actual virtual memory your process takes up.

If Windows kernel Balance Set Manager thinks that your app is inactive, or should be left behind to give other processes more power, it can decide to reduce the working set size. If working set size is smaller than what your application actually needs to work on, you could easily see a lot of page faults because it simply becomes a race between The Balance Set Manager and the application. Usually balance set manager monitors memory usage and can also decide to increase working set size accordingly. However, this might be prevented in certain circumstances like low physical free memory, high I/O (cache stress on physical memory), low process priorty, background/foreground status of the application etc.

It can simply be the behavior of .NET garbage collector due to vast amount of small memory blocks getting allocated and disposed in a very short time, causing a stress on both memory allocation and releasing. The "VM Size" could stay around the same size but behind the scenes it could be continously allocating/freeing memory, causing continous page faults.

Also know that the DLLs the process is using are also accounted for the process statistics. Not your app but one of the COM or .NET DLL you are using might be causing this behavior as well. You can deduce actual culprit by changing your application's behavior (e.g. removing DB access code and only leave object allocation code behind) to see which component is actually causing thrashing.

EDIT: About your question on GC impact on memory thrashing: [The CLR actually grows the heap dynamically and gives the memory back to the OS as needed](http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/05/04/jvm-vs-clr-memory-allocation/). That does not occur synchronously. GC runs behind the scenes and frees memory in large chunks to prevent hindering application performance. Say you are allocating many small objects and freeing them almost immediately. That causes many references to stay for a moment in memory before freeing. It is easy to imagine that it becomes like a head-to-head race between the garbage collector and the memory allocating code. While GC eventually catches up, the required new memory must be satisified from a "new memory", not the old one because old one is not freed up yet. Since actual memory we are working on stays around the same, balance set manager may not think of giving our process more memory because we're on the edge, always around the same physical memory size but constantly need "newly allocated memory" not "more memory", therefore page faults.

Comment: thanks for such elaborate response. could you please point me to a more or less detailed explanation on how GC induces page swap?

Comment: I know how GC works withing .NET. What I want to learn now is how it refelects on unmanaged part... From your explanation I draw - .NET requests new page / give up old page when GC allocate/abandon a 'GC segment' ? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes pretty much. The thing with unmanaged world is that .NET ends up calling VirtualAlloc and VirtualFree at some point. Due to delayed nature of GC, it's normal to see page faults because OS needs to bring in **new** physical memory to process's virtual space. Remember that a page fault doesn't have to be a "disk I/O". It could simply be a physical memory remapping.

Answer (score 4):

Page faults are normal. Memory gets swapped out and when you next access it that's a page fault and the system brings it back. This is by design.

I've got an app running on my machine right now with 500 million page faults. There's nothing to worry about!

Answer (score 0):

Page faults means Memory issues

Consider increasing memory, if you have excessive page faults.

Have a large working set size.

The working set is the set of memory pages currently loaded in RAM. This is measured by Process\Working Set. A high value might indicate that you have loaded a number of assemblies.

Process\Working Set has no specific threshold value to watch, although a high or fluctuating value can indicate a memory shortage. A high or fluctuating value accompanied by a high rate of page faults clearly indicates that your server does not have enough memory.

Further reading:

Check memory under System Resources in following MSDN article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647791.aspx#scalenetchapt15_topic9

Please provide some code to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer to this I am currently testing it on my application. Break up your working set into smaller chunks and work with the chunks.

For instance I have a large list of objects (9000-30000). If I break up that list into a chunk of 500 or so at a time it should maintain the 500 objects in memory while I work on them.

You will want to increase or decrease the size of your chunk until you can work with it fast enough that the OS will maintain it in memory. This is theory I haven't fully tested it yet. But it should work.